# Is it good to have multiple views of same data on different views?

Tags: user-centered-design

I have a huge data(around 2000) of startup companies in my platform. we are showing them in different views like compact view, board view, business modal view e.t.c Is it good practice to have data in multiple views & categories..

Comment: Depends on users and content readability, because all we do is present information. Whatever best way possible.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it's good practice depends on the **user needs**. If you have multiple audiences then it's certainly appropriate to have multiple views. Different things are important to different people. This why many reporting dashboards are extensible and modular - flexibility for the breadth of audience preferences and priorities.

I would consider who you are designing for. If  there is more than one, consider which - if any - is most important. Focusing on the audience and what needs you are fulfilling for them will make decisions like this a lot simpler.

Comment: I agree with the audiences but rather than *Different things are important to different people* (which is true), I would say that the way the user analyses the content depends on their goals (because a user can have more than one goal when viewing the site).

Comment: Fair enough, and I feel that's a subset of my point. Whether one goal or many, the exercise of identifying the audience and what they need should expose that.

Comment: Totally agree :)